# Linq Entity Exception not printing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am LINQ to input information from a Database. I have my try.catch block set up to catch these exceptions. However I believe I ran into a sore spot where I am attempting to see what the message is but it just bypass printing the message to me and goes directly to error page. Here is an example of the code I have so far. I would love to get some input on why this seems to be acting so strange.

```
 private void CreateEntry()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Today;
        var version = (from v in house.StayLateVersions
                       where v.Active
                       select v).FirstOrDefault();

        if (version == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }

        //Try to create an entry for the database.  Upon failure, sends the exception to ThrowDbError();

        try
        {
            ResidenceHallInspection rhi = new ResidenceHallInspection();

            rhi.versionId = version.id;
            rhi.submitDate = DateTime.Now;
            rhi.CheckInOrOut = ddlCheck.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Id = txtId.Text;
            rhi.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            rhi.MiddleName = txtMiddleName.Text;
            rhi.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            rhi.Walls = chbxWalls.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Windows = chbxWindows.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Blinds = chbxBlinds.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Couch = chbxCouch.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomCouch = chbxCRCouch.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomChair = chbxCRChair.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Doors = chbxDoors.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Carpet = chbxCarpet.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Ceiling = chbxCeiling.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.CommonRoomCounter = chbxCRCounter.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Cabinet = chbxCabinet.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Phone = chbxPhone.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Bed = chbxBed.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Desk = chbxDesk.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.DeskChairs = chbxDeskChair.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Tub = chbxTub.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Vanity = chbxVanity.SelectedItem.Text;
            rhi.Notes = txtNotes.Text;
            rhi.Building = txtResHall.Text;
            rhi.ApartmentNumber = txtSuitNo.Text;
            rhi.BedSpace = txtBedSpace.Text;

            house.AddToResidenceHallInspections(rhi);
            house.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception oe)
        {
            ThrowDbError(oe);
            Response.Write(oe.InnerException);
        }
    }

    /*=================================================*/
    /*Possible Errors                                  */
    /*=================================================*/

    private void ThrowDbError(Exception oe)
    {
        Response.Write(oe.Source);
        house.Dispose();
        Session.Contents.Add("FormException", oe);
        Response.Redirect("/Database-Error/", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for that to happen is that you are running the database `version` query outside the try/catch block. Any exception in this db access code will not be handled by the code you have shown above.

Try extending your `try` block to also include the db access code:

```
var version = (from v in house.StayLateVersions
                   where v.Active
                   select v).FirstOrDefault();

if (version == null)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

and see if this time the error is caught.

Comment: can you try to debug and set a breakpoint in the `catch` block on the `ThrowDbError(oe);` line? I have the feeling that the error is caught, but `ThrowDbError` does a redirect and the error is not shown.

Comment: On my local machine it runs fine but its when it is uploaded and ran live thats when the problem occurs

Comment: @Robertpurpose there could also be a problem with the fact that you are doing `Response.Write` after `Response.Redirect` when an error occurs. Try logging the message to a file/db instead of doing the `Response.Write`

Comment: doesnt seem to be sending the error. Is there a way to find this on the server?

Comment: You can try handling errors at a global level (ex: in globals.asax). Before doing that, please check that you have the right binaries on the server (perhaps do a rebuild+redeploy)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25100/discussion-between-robertpurpose-and-w0lf)